# Data Visualisation of Ball Bounces

Tags: data-visualization

Suppose we have three types of balls made of materials A, B and C.

If we wanted to investigate the potential deterioration in performance of each ball material over time by comparing the first bounce height and the 3rd bounce height, what sort of graphical representation should I use? My guesss is to use a side-by-side boxplot.

The data is,

[image]

If using box-plots aren't ideal, what would you recommend?

Comment: Have you considered plotting the difference? Plotting bounce1-bounce3 would help control for the initial bounce height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plot that captures change in bounce height over time, grouped by material:

[image: change in bounce height over time by material]

The black diamonds represent group means, through which the lines are drawn.

I rearranged the data by bounce number, to make it easier to work with:

```
   bounce.height ball.material bounce.number
1            2.7             A             1
2            2.6             A             1
3            2.3             A             1
4            2.8             A             1
5            1.7             B             1
6            1.5             B             1
7            1.6             B             1
8            1.8             B             1
9            3.4             C             1
10           3.2             C             1
11           3.1             C             1
12           3.0             C             1
13           1.7             A             3
14           1.5             A             3
15           1.1             A             3
16           1.9             A             3
17           1.1             B             3
18           0.9             B             3
19           0.9             B             3
20           1.1             B             3
21           2.4             C             3
22           2.2             C             3
23           2.1             C             3
24           2.0             C             3
```

Full code:

```
# rearrange data
bounce.height <- c(2.7,2.6,2.3,2.8, 1.7,1.5,1.6,1.8, 3.4,3.2,3.1,3.0, 1.7,1.5,1.1,1.9, 1.1,0.9,0.9,1.1, 2.4,2.2,2.1,2.0)
ball.material <- c('A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C','C', 'A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C','C')
bounce.number <- c( 1,  1,  1,  1,   1,  1,  1,  1,   1,  1,  1,  1,   3,  3,  3,  3,   3,  3,  3,  3,   3,  3,  3,  3)

bounce.data <- data.frame(bounce.height, ball.material, bounce.number)
bounce.data

library(ggplot2)

# plot bounce heights as points
ggplot(bounce.data, 
       aes(x = bounce.number, 
           y = bounce.height, 
           group = ball.material, 
           color = ball.material,
           shape = ball.material)) +
geom_point() +

# plot group means as black diamonds
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, 
             color = "black", 
             geom = "point", 
             shape = 18, 
             aes(group = ball.material)) +

# plot lines through group means
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, 
             geom = "line",
             linetype="dashed",
             aes(group = ball.material, 
                 color = ball.material)) +

# control y-axis limits
ylim(0.5,3.5)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you elected not to show all the information inherent in the dataset?  Your plotting model would suggest connecting *individual* bounce heights rather than *average* bounce heights, and that would be easy to do.

Comment: @whuber I plotted lines through group means because I don't know how to plot lines through the pairs of individual bounce heights. If it's simple, maybe you can point me in the right direction? I looked at some examples of related `ggplot` questions on SO but wasn't able to adapt any of the answers to the task at hand. I must be missing something.

Comment: Use `geom_segment`.  Here's an example: `X <- data.frame(Material=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=4),
        Id=factor(rep(1:4, 3)),
        Height.1=c(27,26,23,28,17,15,16,18,34,32,31,30)/10,
        Height.3=c(17,15,11,19,11,9,9,11,24,22,21,20)/10);
ggplot(X, aes(color=Material, linetype=Material, shape=Id)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=3, y=Height.1, yend=Height.3)) +
  geom_point(aes(1, Height.1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(3, Height.3)) + 
  xlab("Bounce") + ylab("Height") + ylim(0, NA)`  Note the use of a true zero for the vertical axis to eliminate the exaggeration in relative heights.